# How do I generate Xpath (at run time in my script) for a web element using python?

Tags: python, selenium, xpath, xml-parsing, html-parsing

I am trying to export page-objects of any web page using python [data scraping] in a text file. Also I am providing the hard coded Selenium web driver syntax for the elements.

I am able to achieve this by using `id` attribute. 
For example I am finding all the web elements having attribute `id` and input of type `text`:

```
from htmldom import htmldom
URL = "https://www.fundsindia.com/content/jsp/registration/login.jsp#SignIn.com/"
dom = htmldom.HtmlDom(URL)
dom = dom.createDom()

#retrieves all the elements with ids and "type=text"
p_id = dom.find("[id]")    
for id in p_id.filter("[type=text]"):
    print (("\t" + "WebElement" + " %s " + "= " + 'driver.findElement(By.id("%s"))')%(id.attr("id"),id.attr("id")) + "\n")
```

This will give output as:

```
WebElement userName = driver.findElement(By.id("userName"))

WebElement emailId = driver.findElement(By.id("emailId"))

WebElement mobileNumber = driver.findElement(By.id("mobileNumber"))

WebElement userMailId = driver.findElement(By.id("userMailId"))
```

In a similar way, I want to use `xpath` in place of `id`. For example

```
WebElement userMailId = driver.findElement(By.xpath("x_path"))
```

Could anyone help to find out `x_path` ? I have spent hours and still no success, I am wondering if it's even possible in this world?

Please suggest.

Comment: @jainish I know what an xpath is and how to make one. However I want to generate xpath during run time using python. That means automatically. Please refer the example I have given.

Comment: `XPath` is not a particular value. There could be dozens of options. What kind of `XPath` you want to use? Absolute `XPath`, search by one exact attribute, by all attributes, by text, bound to parent node...?

Comment: @Andersson Thanks for asking this, I was waiting for this one. Relative `xpath` would work for me and regarding attributes, I would prefer `id` or `name` as for now, to understand this. That's why I have given the example of fetching the `id` at run time using python.

Comment: I'm curious to know if the method proposed below works for you.

Comment: @EttoreRizza The `xpath` provided by your solution is correct. However it's never advisable to use absolute `xpath` (need to use relative `xpath` instead), as this one can fail to locate element in future in case of any changes in the parent class.

Comment: How about the edited version ?

Comment: @EttoreRizza Right now I am using this format only but with `htmldom` in `python`. However lot of web elements don't have ids or names and I need to create relative xpath for them during run time.

Answer (score -1):

**xpath** is the xml path of the webelement that traces down the location of that specific element from root node (`<html>`) in **DOM**.

There are basically two type of xpaths : *absolute* and *relative*.  There is a plugin for firefox browser called Firepath that will assist you in creating *absolute* xpaths. As a beginner,  Use firepath with firebug addon.

Relative xpaths are crafted for dynamic webelements as they locate webelements by relative position of that element with respect to other elements in node. They are short and concise in length . To learn the art of creating relative xpath , pay a visit at [w3schools](https://www.w3schools.com/xml/xpath_intro.asp).

Comment: I am not looking to find xpath manually. Please read the description in detail in case you missed something or let me know if you need more details.